# Weird Footer background color issues - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having really weird background-color issues in my footer area, however there is no color set to the footer

When the page is <767px (with a local background image in 'intro div') there is a white rectangular shape in the middle that disappears when below <400px

However, with an image online, the footer is greyish and covering the image at the bottom

Can anybody help with why my footer is acting like this? I dont want a background there and have tried -background-color transparent

**CODE : http://www.codeply.com/go/pCnHr5FVQD**

---

**EDIT:**

new Link (shows problem better) - the white space at the bottom is the problem - the top is being cut of i dont know why

**http://www.codeply.com/go/y0gCHBcFRK**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your markup

```
<footer class="footer intro">
```

and it tries to apply this style:

```
.intro {
    background: url("https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AABG9mhs84HNzOHrKXQkO64GBv-iDm1fZXJSK8Ok6afmvg/12/59553372/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/Final6copy.jpg/CNzsshwgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygC/yF1LdOBKWfD5mhYODe_ItLcWQsDjS6Z34HrBh8HSRUo%2CTV9UN0usD5Sdozz-Kit6VyRnEIsgHlS3eZn-eK6Qqm0%2CGXHc2baQtsLLewvmoqeq10LqcQOmq5NMTIoogflWpok%2C17ahfhDJA9sLM0q0M7Bm003sn7K_n0cHs9ShPpvlOxo?size=1024x768&size_mode=2");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Most of the images that you have used are returning 404. It's hard to see what the issue is..  I can only speculate.

Comment: Yes I understand and that was purposely added - However without 'intro' class in the footer - the footer is all white and nothing changes it

Comment: Firstly, can you see this issue in the demo that you have put up? because I cannot.

Comment: I noticed one thing.. opening chrome dev tools on that link seem to fix the issue. Let me dig around a little bit and get back to you.